# Laravel HasManyThrough nor BelongsToMany doesn't work in my case. Is it database structure problem?

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent, laravel-nova

I have 3 tables of:

```
products table
- id
- title
- etc.
```

```
purchases table
- id
- code
- etc.
```

```
purchase_products table
- id
- purchase_id
- product_id
- qty
- etc.
```

My goal is to retrieve purchases for a single product. The following relationship doesn't work for me. Tried different ways with `belongsToMany`, not working either.

```
$this->hasManyThrough(
            Purchase::class,
            PurchaseProduct::class,
            'purchase_id',
            'product_id',
            'id',
            'id'
        );
```

In a simple way I could fetch all purchase products by product_id and then retrieve purchases, however I need a relationship for this to work, because of Laravel nova as I want to display purchases on a resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product Model

```
class Product {
    public function purchases()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Purchase::class, 'purchase_products', 'product_id', 'purchase_id');
    }
}
```

Purchase Model

```
class Purchase {
    public function products()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'purchase_products', 'purchase_id', 'product_id');
    }
}
```